# getting error in user_profile form submition

Tags: django, django-forms

I am getting error `user_profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'phoneNumber'` 
Using the post method and trying to post data to the database but getting this error.

model.py

```
class user_profile(models.Model):
 user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 phoneNumber=models.CharField( max_length=12, blank=True)
 name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
 address=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
```

user_profile.html

```
 {% extends 'firmApp/basic.html'%}
 {% block body%}
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <form action="/user_profile/" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="name" class="form-label">Full-Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" >
          <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="phoneNumber" class="form-label">Contact Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber">
          </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="formFile" class="form-label">select image</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="formFile">
          </div>
    
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

{%endblock%}

views.py

```
def  user_profile(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    phoneNumber=request.POST.get('phoneNumber')
    name=request.POST.get('Name')
    address=request.POST.get('address')
    user=request.user
    print(user)
    profile=user_profile(phoneNumber=phoneNumber, name=name, address=address,user=user)
    profile.save()
return render(request, "firmApp/blog/user_profile.html")
```

I have checked the complete code but am unable to solve the issue. I am getting below error

```
user_profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'phoneNomber'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a naming clash - both your view and your model are called user_profile. When you try to create the model in your view, python is actually calling the view instead of the model. The view function doesn't expect to receive the `phoneNumber` argument, hence the error. You just need to change one of the names to something distinct.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your view and model have the same name and since you're calling `user_profile` from inside the view, it's calling the wrong `user_profile`. You should rename one of them in order to have distinct names and solve your error.

According to the conventions, class names should be written like `UserProfile`.